# How to convert enum to type

Tags: c#, string, types, enums

I have a enum like this.

```
public enum eTypeVar
{
    Int,
    Char,
    Float
};
```

and I want to convert it to type , to do something like this:

```
eTypeVar type=eTypeVar .Int;
string str= eTypeVar.ToString .ToLower();
(str as type) a=1;
```

How would I do it?

Comment: Where is the enum? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It might be better if you can explain the problem you're trying to solve instead of the solution you're trying to create.

Comment: i have enum that contains "int" "char" ec

Comment: i want to use in the enum for define and check values of variable

Comment: You are really going to need to articulate your question a bit better than this.

Comment: i cant convert a string to type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is:

```
Dictionary<eTypeVar, Type> _Types = new Dictionary<eTypeVar, Type> {
    { eTypeVar.Int, typeof(Int32) },
    { eTypeVar.Char, typeof(Char) },
    { eTypeVar.Float, typeof(Single) }
};

public Boolean Check(eTypeVar type, Object value)
{
    return value.GetType() == _Types[type];
}
```

<strike>You cannot convert a variable into a type for another variable declaration. You should rethink your design. Anyway it doesn't make sence what you are doing. If you know that you want to use a int, why not declare it:</strike>

```
String name = "int";
int value = 1;
```

If you want to have dynamic code for some reasons you could use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and a generic method.

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T value)
{
    ....
}
```

Then you can [construct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) the method at runtime using reflection and [invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke.aspx) it. But at this time i think you need more basics of C# to work with this features.

Comment: i create a variable with this enum, and i want to check if the value suitable to his type

Comment: @HodayaShalom You cannot create a variable from a variable. Variable types are compile-time constants and not defined at runtime. For what purpose do you need your "dynamic" variable?

Comment: in my program the user can to create variable, for that

Comment: i need it only for checks only! not for define, how i know the type without to do switch with the options of the enum

Comment: @HodayaShalom Added something that should fit your needs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) such as:

```
YourEnumType realValue = Enum.Parse(typeof(YourEnumType), "int");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...
for example you have enum like this

```
  public enum Emloyee
 {
   None = 0,
  Manager = 1,
  Admin = 2,
  Operator = 3
}
```

then convert enum to this

```
Emloyee role = Emloyee.Manager;
int roleInterger = (int)role;
```

end for enum to string..

```
Emloyee role = Emloyee.Manager;
string roleString = role.ToString();
```